# Hibernate's saveOrUpdate ignores not-null column property

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have a mapping file that specifies a given column as `not-null="true"`. This is a mistake since the table's column is set to `NULL` on the Oracle database. But we did not notice that until now, more than an year after creating the mapping file, because Hibernate have been "ignoring" this. Is that possible?

To make it clearer. On the database:

> `CREATE TABLE db.my_table
>
>   (...)
>
>   my_column NUMBER(10,0)   NULL,
>   (...)`

On the mapping file:

> `<column name="MY_COLUMN" precision="10" scale="0" not-null="true">`

Then on the Java code:

> `getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(myEntity);`
>
> `getHibernateTemplate().flush();`

This code is WORKING on our environment. Has always been. But some clients have had issues of `ot-null property references a null or transient value` and when I debugged the code it didn't make any sense. This code should never been able to run, as far as I know.

Of course it's simple to solve the clients problems, I just have to correct the mapping file so it represents my entity properly. But the real issue here is why haven't Hibernate complained about it?

I've asked some other engineers here with more experience on Hibernate but none of them have ever seen this.

So, can anyone gimme a hint?

**EDIT:** Just want to stress that both our test environment and my client's are running the exact same code, and in both cases the `myEntity` object has the `myColumn` property set to `NULL`. So, what puzzles me is why it does not yield any exception here on our environment.

Comment: It's a bug. I guess every piece of software has one.

Comment: It surely smells like a bug. But I wonder why it does not happen on our environment, but only on our clients'.

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely correct behaviour.

The `not-null` attribute has two meanings:

- support schema exporting tools
- check the Entity in runtime (i.e. do not check database column setting)

See: [5.1. Mapping declaration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration), extract:

> The mapping document also contains some extra optional attributes and
>   elements that affect the database schemas exported by the schema
>   export tool (for example, the not-null attribute).

And [5.1.11. Property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property), extract:

> **not-null** (optional): enables the DDL generation of a nullability
>   constraint for the columns.

So, if your clients run some code, which tries:

```
getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(myEntity);
```

while the `myEntity` is missing some property set as `not-null="true"` it is correct in throwing a runtime exception. While in your test environment you most likely always set the property to *some* not null value.

*And there is an advantage even. The DB and App are loosely coupled. So if needed, you can make more constraints on App side, while not touching the DB (e.g. you are not allowed)*

Comment: That it has influence on the DDL makes sense, but, the other part, I'm confused: a call to `getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(myEntity);` where `myEntity` has the property mapped to `MY_COLUMN` with `null` will yield a runtime error or not?

Comment: If there is a mapping: `not-null=true`, and entity has NULL instead of value... it will end up in runtime error. In fact, in exception: *not-null property references a null or transient value*

Comment: Ok, got it! Maybe you should consider changing that *"So, if your clients run some code, which tries: `getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(myEntity);`
while the `myEntity` is missing some property set as `not-null="true"` **it is correct**."* part. That last (bold) part is what got me confused. I'd expect something like "it is correct in throwing a runtime exception." or similar. Anyway, good answer! +1!

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion and help with clarification. My English still represents my Czech thinking ;) thanks

Comment: I get your point @radim-kohler. But both our environment and my client's are running the exact same code. And when debugging **here** the `myEntity` has the same attribute sel to `NULL` but it does not yields any exception. That's what puzzles me. I'll edit my question to stress this out.

Comment: I tried again right now (as I did few hours ago) to be sure. It really does throw exception (at least in my case and it should do the same in common). It is hard to say what is wrong, but environment of your client, and mine are doing correct job. What is happening localy, is hard to say. Maybe some AOP exception filter... Sorry I do not have better answer ;(

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem:

In my hibernate mapping file I had set `not-null="true"` for a special column.

On my development machine I could persist null values **without any exceptions**. On the customers machine we **always received** a `PropertyValueException / DataIntegrityViolationException`.

This was a dangerous behavior. Manual and automatic tests would not fail.

**Solution:**

On my development machine I hat to set the property `hibernate.check_nullability` to `true`. Only then I also got the exceptions on my development system.

**Conclusion**

This strange behavior could come from adding the `hibernate validator` to the classpath. This turns `check_nullability` to false.
See this related question: [How to Enable Spring Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898122/how-to-enable-spring-validation)

Somehow this only applies on my dev-system and not in production. This might root from a different dependency loading within different application servers.