# How to Enable Spring Validation

Tags: spring, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

After putting hibernate-validator.jar and javax.validation-api.jar in my classpath the my old validation turned off and **org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException** is replaced by **org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException** which wraps SQL exception that is coming from table constraints and this is causing a lot of issues.

It automatically turned JSR-303 validation on so it doesn't validate anything anymore.

I have to put this two jars to be able to upgrade Jersey to 2.4, it has dependency on these two jars.

Putting these properties into hibernate.properties file doesn't help, hibernate simply ignores them but it loads the properties on start-up

loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl=false,hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners=false etc}

```
javax.persistence.validation.mode=none
hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners=false
hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl=false
```

I am using Spring 3.2.4 with SessionFactory and mapping resources from hbm.xml files with constraints in it, hibernate 3.6.9.final, hibernate-validator 5.0.final, javax.validator-api 1.1.0.Final

I just can't figure out how to enable spring validation when hibernate.validator in my classpath, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding hibernate validator to the classpath turns off hibernate core validation, so I had to add this property to turn it back on

```
<prop key="hibernate.check_nullability">true</prop>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Bean Validation by setting `javax.persistence.validation.mode` to `none` in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` (or `persistence.xml` when working with JPA).

Just out of interest, you seem to have constraint annotations on your model (otherwise you shouldn't see a `ConstrainViolationException`, so I'm wondering why you don't want to validate them?

Comment: Adding javax.persistence.validation.mode=none hibernate.cfg.xml is not working. I already validate those constraints with spring validation mechanism, adding hibernate.validator to my classpath has been causing validation problems, it has become the default validator. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace which shows where the `ConstraintViolationException` exactly is thrown? Maybe its another component than Hibernate?

Comment: Now It doesn't throw any exception. I want to turn my hibernate validator on not JSR-303. Do you know how? I want it to throw PropertyValueException Thanks so much

Comment: Hibernate Validator is an implementation of JSR 303 (more precisely, HV 5 implements JSR 349 which is Bean Validation 1.1), so there is no way to get one without the other.

Comment: I was meaning Hibernate core validation. At the moment I cannot use both of them (303-349) I need to use hibernate core validation.